# Efficient way to enable rails submit button on updating checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I disable update submit buttons in all forms, and enable them on keyup.

```
$(function(){
  $("#submitAccount, #submitProfile, #submitUser").attr("disabled","true");
  $(".form-control").keyup(function(){
    $("#submitAccount").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

The problem is, in my users edit form, I also have some checkboxes to set some permissions.

What would be an efficient way to remove the disabled attribute on checking/unchecking one of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitAccount").prop("disabled", true); // Disable buttons

    $(":checkbox").
        on('click', function() {
            $("#submitAccount").prop("disabled", $(':checkbox:checked').length > 0);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to append the checkboxes checking to the keyup  event, since I have both text input fields and checkboxes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I need a much simpler solution so I ended up doing this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#submitAccount, #submitProfile, #submitUser").attr("disabled","true");
  $(".form-control").keyup(function(){
    $("#submitAccount, #submitProfile, #submitUser").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $("#submitUser").removeAttr("disabled");
  })
});
```